# Parametrization using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline job in Azure Data Factory which I want to use to run the pipeline job but pass all files for a specific month through for example.

I have a folder called 2020/01 inside this folder is numerous files with different names.

The question is: Can one pass a parameter through to only extract and load the files for 2020/01/01 and 2020/01/02 if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is: Can one pass a parameter through to only extract and
>   load the files for 2020/01/01 and 2020/01/02 if that makes sense?

You did't mention which connector you are using in pipeline job,but you mentioned `folder` in your question.As i know,the majority folder path could be parametrization in ADF copy activity configuration.

You could create a param :

[image]

Then apply it in the `wildcard folder path`:

[image]

Even if your files' names have same prefix,you could apply `01*.json` on the `wildcard file name property`.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent, Thanks Jay it worked and i can now run my pipeline jobs passing through the month or even day level.

Really appreciate your response, have a fantastic day.

Regards

Rayno

Comment: Cheers! You're so kind.